# AWS - t2.micro instance EBS Volume size

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I was trying to create t2.micro instance via AWS console.

I hope its free for one year, but it does not come with any instance storage.

So i wanted to add EBS Volume in this instance? is it free?

What is the maximum EBS volume i can add in t2.micro as free?

```
Model   vCPU    CPU Credits / hour
Mem (GiB)    Storage
t2.micro    1   6   1   EBS-Only
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

30 GB of EBS is comes with the Free Tier. Go ahead use the 30 GB of EBS.

You can break it and use it either way want like 20 + 5 + 3 + 2 GB [ with magnetic or Genral Purpose SSD ].

[image]

Comment: Is 30gb for all instance in a zone. or for each instance 30GB available ?