# Amazon EC2: MySql Database storage?

Tags: mysql, linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cloud

I do have a Linux instance in Amazon EC2. After installing the Linux instance, I simply installed `apache` and set up a `MySQL` database inside it via console. Now I do have questions.

1. Where is my database is located exactly? I can simply access it via `phpMyAdmin` like in the same way we do in desktop PCs. Is my database in `Amazon EBS` ?
2. How do I know the storage price for the information stored inside my mysql database?

Comment: Yes your database is in the EBS. You need to open the ports in order to access the database on a local machine.

Comment: @Developer: OK, Thank you. If my EBS volume is 100GB, that means the max size of the mysql DB is 100GB (or maybe bit low), right?

Comment: From this statement by AWS: "After a volume is attached to an instance, you can use it like any other physical hard drive."It may be containing other files too e.g apache files in your case. So, It depends on  how many services you install.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Normally Linux store MySQL information `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` file, then find `datadir` path inside the file. You can read the file using `cat` command.

The result will be like this

```
$ cat /etc/mysql/my.cnf
#
# The MySQL database server configuration file.
#
# You can copy this to one of:
# - "/etc/mysql/my.cnf" to set global options,
# - "~/.my.cnf" to set user-specific options.
# 
[mysqld]
#
# * Basic Settings
#
user   = mysql
pid-file = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket  = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port   = 3306
basedir  = /usr
datadir  = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir  = /tmp
language = /usr/share/mysql/english
```

2. EC2 instance use EBS for storage you can check price storage detail [here](https://aws.amazon.com/ebs/pricing/)

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. So you mean My database is in EBS?

Comment: Database is here `datadir  = /var/lib/mysql`

Comment: Your answer is correct, but it is not much convincing. However I found the below 2 links, which shows that your answer is correct. Positing for the benifit of others

https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/

and

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30210130/aws-t2-micro-instance-ebs-volume-size